# Can we do this in SQL? =SUM(ColumnCellValue * 1.2)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sql, excel

I have a spreadsheet of products that a client has given me, which I insert into the DB Table using Navicat SQL Server - and he wants to increase all the pricing by 20% - Which way would be better, just to do it in Excel? And then insert it into the DB, or should I just do a SQL query on the columns to increase all the prices, and if so, how shoud I increase each row value by 20%?

Comment: The tags were there for a reason dude.

Comment: They are relevant. A comment below proves my point.

Comment: No. They have nothing to do with the question itself. Being tangentially related to the circumstances in which your question arose is irrelevant. I'm not going to bother cleaning up after you *again* since the question is closed anyway, but a glance at your profile indicates this is a chronic problem. **Stop misusing the tagging system.**

Answer (score 7):

You can update the price in the table directly in SQL Management Studio.  Why bring Excel into the mix?

```
Update Products
Set Price = Price * 1.2
```

Comment: Yeah, just 'cause I'd eventually have to enter new stuff into the Excel file anyway, but I'll leave that up to my client I guess. Anyhow.. Thanks :D Very simple answer

Comment: Um; I got this message: `Arithmetic overflow error converting nvarchar to data type numeric.
The statement has been terminated.`

Comment: What is the data type of the field your price data is stored in?

Comment: Update Products
Set Price = Cast((Cast(Price as numeric) * 1.2) as nvarchar(TheLengthYouDefinedInTheTableForTheField)

Comment: Thank you - But I just put the query in a webpage, and it ust gives me this error now: `database.Execute("UPDATE Products SET 'Unit Price' = 'Unit Price' * 1.2");`

Comment: The exact same syntax works when inserting into the db and updating the db and selecting from the db, and i also use SUM on one of my pages, but this one seems to think it's wrong syntax :S It works everywhere else with the same syntax

Comment: What environment are you getting the error?  Visual Studio, SQL Server Management Studio, etc?

Comment: I'm using WebMatrix, razor.. c#..

Answer (score 2):

both ways are possible you should select the best appropriate way to do this.  if you are updating sql table for some other purpose updating the sql table will be the ideal solution for you

in sql you can use following code to do the update

```
update TableName
set DesiredColumnName = DesiredColumnName * 1.2
--if you need to filter the records you can use a where clause as well
```

hope this will work for you

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the answer - Maybe you could try help explain this syntax error I get?: `database.Execute("UPDATE Products SET 'Unit Price' = 'Unit Price' * 1.2");` - It doesn't make sense. The same syntax works accross my whole site, its only breaking when I try to multiply

Comment: try it by changing 'Unit Price' = 'Unit Price'  to "Unit Price = Unit Price" without the single quote

Comment: Spaces probably won't work too well depending on the database engine.  If MSSQL, try database.Execute("UPDATE Products SET [Unit Price] = [Unit Price] * 1.2");

Comment: can you please send me the code of database.execute() method this issue may arrising because of the driver you are using,

Comment: I did send you the code, in my first comment. But here it is again: `database.Execute("UPDATE Products SET 'Unit Price' = 'Unit Price' * 1.2"); `